# record contents of packets dropped in iptables

Tags: iptables, tcpdump, packet

I'm trying to find a way to record the entire contents of packets (possibly with tcpdump) that have been dropped according to rules in iptables.

At present, I have a rule to log these packets (with a log prefix), then follow this with a rule to drop them.

Is there a way to record the contents of those packets for review **afterwards**?

So, I'm looking for this:

1. A rule that logs the matching packet
2. A rule that passes the packet to a new target that records its contents (maybe QUEUE target?)
3. A rule that drops the packet

2 & 3 may even be combined.

My understanding is that tcpdump may not be able to do this as it examines packets *before* iptables and therefore will not record just the dropped packets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NFLOG target can be used for this purpose. Here is a very basic example:

```
# Drop traffic by default
iptables -P INPUT DROP

# add your whitelists here
# iptables -A INPUT ...

# Pass the packets to NFLOG (just like LOG, but instead of syslog,
# it uses netlink). You can add extra filters such as '-p tcp' as usual
iptables -A INPUT -j NFLOG
# packets that get here will now be dropped per INPUT policy

# Finally you can use tcpdump to capture from this interface (there
# can only be one active user of nflog AFAIK)
tcpdump -i nflog ...
```

Refer to the `iptables-extensions` manual page for a description of the `NFLOG` target.